# no known class method for selector 'scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval with timer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, selector

I have tried to figure out this, by reading other threads here - but I have not been able to work out anything so far.
If it's be just being a novice that doesn't understand the connections I need to make or if I doesn't have any relevance - I don't know.

I am making an iPhone app with 2 timers in it.

I am working on getting the source code for the timer to work.

I use a flip side application template from xcode, as I want to use the flip side for settings later on (where you can customize timers

In my MainViewController.h:

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"
#import "UIKit/UIKit.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate> {

IBOutlet UILabel *timerP1;
IBOutlet UILabel *timerP2;

NSTimer *myTimerP1;
NSTimer *myTimerP2;
}

- (IBAction)startP1;
- (IBAction)stopP1;
- (IBAction)resetP1;

- (void)showActivityP1;

- (IBAction)startP2;
- (IBAction)stopP2;
- (IBAction)resetP2;

- (void)showActivityP2;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *flipsidePopoverController;

@end
```

In my MainViewController.m:

```
@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (IBAction)startP1{

myTimerP1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(showActivityP1) userinfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
- (IBAction)stopP1{

[myTimerP1 invalidate];
}
- (IBAction)resetP1{

timerP1.text = @"60";
}

- (void)showActivityP1;{

int currentTimeP1 = [timerP1.text intValue];
int newTimeP1 = currentTimeP1 - 1;
timerP1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newTimeP1];
}
- (IBAction)startP2{

}
- (IBAction)stopP2{

}
- (IBAction)resetP2{

}

- (void)showActivityP2{

}
```

I get the error "No known class method for selector 'scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userinfo:repeats:'

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here?

Well, frankly what you're doing wrong is not using autocompletion.
It's a small typo, nothing to worry about.

`userinfo` should be `userInfo` (note the capital `I`)

So the complete call becomes:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(showActivityP1) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:YES];
```

Oh and by the way `- (void)showActivityP1;{...}` will cause you troubles as well, just drop the `;`

Comment: thank you very much :)
I'll try to use that autocomplete more, just need to get used to it